# Lyapunov function for the study of a problem with a parameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A dynamic system **depending on the parameter a** is given.

$$x’’+x’=x(a-1)(sin(x)-a).$$

How to use the Lyapunov function equal to the total energy of the system to find all the equilibrium positions belonging to the segment.

How to show stable destinies on a biffurcation diagram?

I know that in (0,0) is unstable point but why? Are there other unstable points?

Analyse should be belong the diapason $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

Comment: hint: multiply both sides with $x'(t)$, then rearrange so that one side is $(x')^2$ and the other is something that is a total derivative of $t$ of some function $V(x)$ for $x=x(t)$; that $V$ "thing" is *a* Lyapunov function. Also, this is not a question about physics, per se, it is more likely to get better answers at the https://math.stackexchange.com/.